# Converting Dictionary to Yaml Object - not preserving quotations

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I am trying to dynamically create stubby.yml configuration file. I have a template yaml file as follows:

```
resolution_type: GETDNS_RESOLUTION_STUB

dns_transport_list:

  - GETDNS_TRANSPORT_TLS

tls_authentication: GETDNS_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED

tls_query_padding_blocksize: 128

edns_client_subnet_private : 1

round_robin_upstreams: 1

idle_timeout: 10000

listen_addresses:

  - 10.7.0.1

appdata_dir: "/var/cache/stubby"
```

I am trying to append this native yaml configuration

```
upstream_recursive_servers:

  - address_data: 185.228.168.168

    tls_auth_name: "family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org"

  - address_data: 185.228.169.168

    tls_auth_name: "family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org"
```

The stubby configuration will not work without the tls_auth_name values being wrapped in quotations, and also appdata_dir. Quotations are being stripped and i cannot figure out how to dump the yaml without the " being stripped. Even chatgpt is struggling with this one!

```
def get_dns_config(dns_option) -> dict:

    # return stubby.yml configuration

    with open('dns.yml', 'r') as f:

        data = yaml.safe_load(f)

    with open('dns_template.yml', 'r') as f:

        template = yaml.safe_load(f)

        

    template['upstream_recursive_servers'] = data[dns_option]['servers']

    logging.debug(json.dumps(template, indent=4))

    logging.debug(yaml.safe_dump(template, default_flow_style=False,indent=2))

    return yaml.safe_dump(template, default_flow_style=False,indent=2)
```

This is the dict after adding the upstream_recursive_servers value:

```
{
    "resolution_type": "GETDNS_RESOLUTION_STUB",
    "dns_transport_list": [
        "GETDNS_TRANSPORT_TLS"
    ],
    "tls_authentication": "GETDNS_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED",
    "tls_query_padding_blocksize": 128,
    "edns_client_subnet_private": 1,
    "round_robin_upstreams": 1,
    "idle_timeout": 10000,
    "listen_addresses": [
        "10.7.0.1"
    ],
    "appdata_dir": "/var/cache/stubby",
    "upstream_recursive_servers": [
        {
            "address_data": "185.228.168.168",
            "tls_auth_name": "family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org"
        },
        {
            "address_data": "185.228.169.168",
            "tls_auth_name": "family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the result from yaml.safe_load()

```
appdata_dir: /var/cache/stubby
dns_transport_list:
- GETDNS_TRANSPORT_TLS
edns_client_subnet_private: 1
idle_timeout: 10000
listen_addresses:
- 10.7.0.1
resolution_type: GETDNS_RESOLUTION_STUB
round_robin_upstreams: 1
tls_authentication: GETDNS_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED
tls_query_padding_blocksize: 128
upstream_recursive_servers:
- address_data: 185.228.168.168
  tls_auth_name: family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org
- address_data: 185.228.169.168
  tls_auth_name: family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org
```

Apologies for the long post - didn't want to miss anything out.

Answer (score -1):

In the YAML file the record

```yaml
"family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org"
```

denotes the string `family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org` without quotes: the quotes at the beginning and at the end are part of the **representation**, but aren't a part of the **data**.

For make the record to denote the string `"family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org"` (with quotes) you could write whole that string inside single quotes:

```yaml
'"family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org"'
```

That way is described in [YAML specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#23-scalars) in the Example 2.17.

Alternatively, you may write whole that string inside double quotes, but escape the inner double quotes:

```yaml
"\"family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org\""
```

Comment: Thank for your response Tsyvarev. I have just tried both methods but unfortunately they produced '"family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org"'

Comment: They produce `'"family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org"'` for Python language (could be checked e.g. online: https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/). In Python outer quotes are needed for represent a string. Content of that string is `"family-filter-dns.cleanbrowsing.org"`, as you wanted. Or do you want something else?

Comment: Understood. The trouble is it's non-comptabilitiy with stubby. stubby -C stubby.yml generates an error when using this value wrapped with '. I've had to resort to using sed to strip the out ' from the value as I wasn't able to resolve it.